# Export image to it's nominal scale

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, export, scale

I am trying to export an image without having to specify the scale and the CRS in the `Export.image.toDrive` function. In order to do this I found online a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313863/exporting-images-in-native-crs-and-resolution) which I tried to apply it on my dataset but it shows an error saying

> Line 46: brdf.projection is not a function.

How can I apply the solution showing in the link to my code?

```
Map.centerObject(table);

// Here I'm trying to set the Bits according to table 'Bitmask for QF_Cloud_Mask'
var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QF_Cloud_Mask');
  //var landWaterBackground = bitwiseExtract(qa, 1, 3)
  var cloudMaskQuality = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4, 5)
  var cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6, 7)
  var shadowDetected = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8)
  var cirrusDetection = bitwiseExtract(qa, 9)
  var snowIceSurface = bitwiseExtract(qa, 10)

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    //.and(landWaterBackground.eq(1)) // Land no Desert
    .and(cloudMaskQuality.eq(3)) // High
    .and(cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator.eq(0)) // Confident Clear
    .and(shadowDetected.eq(0)) // No
    .and(cirrusDetection.eq(0)) // No cloud
    .and(snowIceSurface.eq(0)) // No Snow/Ice
    
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP46A2')
  .filterDate('2018-07-30', '2018-07-31')
  .map(mask_vnpa2_img)

print(dataset)

// Bidirectional Reflectance Distribution Function (BRDF)
var brdf = dataset.select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL');
var brdfVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['black', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red', 'white'],
};

function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}

var myScale = brdf.projection().nominalScale();

Export.image.toDrive({
image: brdf,
description: 'ntl_beijing_30_07',
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table,
scale: myScale.getInfo()
});
```

Also, I tried:

```
var myScale = ee.Image(brdf).projection().nominalScale();

Export.image.toDrive({
image: brdf,
description: 'ntl_beijing_30_07',
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table,
scale: myScale
});
```

But it shows an error saying

> Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection.
> (Error code: 3)

which means (from what I understand) that I am passing an `ImageCollection` although I specified to my code a band (brdf).

Another try I made, where I select the first of the `ImageCollection`:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP46A2')
.filterDate('2018-07-30', '2018-07-31') .map(mask_vnpa2_img)
.first()
```

returns the following error

> Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found
> inconsistent types: Float64 and Byte. (Error code: 3)

**3rd Edit**
A new approach I tried was:

```
Map.centerObject(table);

var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QF_Cloud_Mask');
  var cloudMaskQuality = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4, 5);
  var cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6, 7);
  var shadowDetected = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8);
  var cirrusDetection = bitwiseExtract(qa, 9);
  var snowIceSurface = bitwiseExtract(qa, 10);

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    .and(cloudMaskQuality.eq(3)) // High
    .and(cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator.eq(0)) // Confident Clear
    .and(shadowDetected.eq(0)) // No
    .and(cirrusDetection.eq(0)) // No cloud
    .and(snowIceSurface.eq(0)); // No Snow/Ice
    
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit;
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit);
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1);
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP46A2')
  .filterDate('2018-07-30', '2018-07-31')
  .map(mask_vnpa2_img);

//var brdf = dataset.select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL');

// Get the first image in the collection
var firstImage = ee.Image(dataset.first());

// Get the scale from the first image
var scale = firstImage.projection().nominalScale();

// Export the image to Drive using the native scale
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: firstImage,
  description: 'ntl_beijing_30_07',
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  region: table,
  scale: scale.getInfo(),
});
```

But I am still receiving the same error with the inconsistent data types.

And a [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2324d881275de6b05c18c89242610813) to my (first attempt) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by specifying which image from the `ImageCollection` I wanted, like so:

```
Map.centerObject(table);

// Here I'm trying to set the Bits according to table 'Bitmask for QF_Cloud_Mask'
var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QF_Cloud_Mask');
  var landWaterBackground = bitwiseExtract(qa, 1, 3)
  var cloudMaskQuality = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4, 5)
  var cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6, 7)
  var shadowDetected = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8)
  var cirrusDetection = bitwiseExtract(qa, 9)
  var snowIceSurface = bitwiseExtract(qa, 10)

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    .and(landWaterBackground.eq(1)) // Land no Desert
    .and(cloudMaskQuality.eq(3)) // High
    .and(cloudDetectionResultsConfidenceIndicator.eq(0)) // Confident Clear
    .and(shadowDetected.eq(0)) // No
    .and(cirrusDetection.eq(0)) // No cloud
    .and(snowIceSurface.eq(0)) // No Snow/Ice
    
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP46A2')
  .filterDate('2018-06-01', '2018-06-30')
  .map(mask_vnpa2_img)
  .select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .first()

print(dataset)

// Bidirectional Reflectance Distribution Function (BRDF)
var brdf = dataset.select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL');
var brdfVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['black', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red', 'white'],
};

// Day/Night Band (DNB)
// NightTime Light (NTL)
Map.addLayer(brdf, brdfVis, 'DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL');


function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}

// Get the scale from the first image
var scale = dataset.projection().nominalScale();

// Export the image to Drive using the native scale
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset,
  description: 'ntl_beijing_30_07',
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  region: table,
  scale: scale.getInfo(),
});
```

in the above code, when I called the `var dataset`, I added the `.first()` argument in the end. In this way, I used one image and **not** an `ImageCollection` of one image, and the mask (*QF_Cloud_Mask*) has been applied properly without giving me any errors for incopatible data type when exporting the image. Next, I managed to get the `scale` info properly.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `dataset` is `ee.ImageCollection`. Then, you select one band for each image in `dataset`:

```js
var brdf = dataset.select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL');
```

so `brdf` is still `ee.ImageCollection`. The error `brdf.projection is not a function.` is because `.projection` is a method for a single `ee.Image`, not `ee.ImageCollection`. That also applies to the `Export.image.toDrive` -- you need to either select a single image per each Export task, or reduce the collection to a single image to export.. that depends on what you want to do.

I also recommend taking a look at this related answer for how to use the `.projection()` information to export an image:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443194/67301

Comment: Please see my edit of another try I made where I select the first image of the question and the error I am getting.